# How to get data from a row on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, row

[image][image]I have a list of lists that contain the indexes of the mininum values on each column of a DataFrame that has row and column name going from 0 to 399 (on columns) and 0 to 1595 (on rows). I want to use this list to access the data of another DataFrame. For example, I have the list (43,579,100) and I want to access the 43rd, 579th and 100th value of a column in the second DataFrame. However, this DataFrame has row number names that do not go from 0 to 1595 so I don't want to make the mistake of accessing the data on the row that may have the name "43", I want to access the 43rd row.

I added a picture of my Data Frames.

I would like to get a list with the data on the selected rows.

Comment: Please provide an extract of your data as text and the expected output

Comment: hi, I just edited my question.

Comment: Please provide it as text, images are useless they cannot be copy/pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.values` to convert the column data to a numpy array and index with your list. For example, if your data is in variable `df` and the list of indexes is `idxs`, then for a given `column`:

```
df[column].values[idxs]
```